# OpenCV in WinRT and C++ - How to do simple face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-runtime, face-detection

I'm an experienced C# developer, but finding C++ vastly different. I've been trying to hack up the [CameraCaptureUI Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac/sourcecode?fileId=58119&pathId=223243806) to do face detection. I have built the Microsoft supplied project for open cv with winrt [here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/opencv). I'm afraid I don't have a very specific question, just why doesn't this work? I get an exception on faceHaar.detectMultiScale() but cannot inspect it (too c++ stupied to know how).
My goal is to do the recognition in a winrt component so I can do my app in C# but this is baby step #1. Here is the relevant code in CapturePhoto.xaml.cpp:

```
    inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        throw Platform::Exception::CreateException(hr);
    }
}

byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ buffer)
{
    // Cast to Object^, then to its underlying IInspectable interface.
    Platform::Object^ obj = buffer;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IInspectable> insp(reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(obj));

    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    ThrowIfFailed(insp.As(&bufferByteAccess));

    // Retrieve the buffer data.
    byte* pixels = nullptr;
    ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels));
    return pixels;
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoked when CapturePhoto button is clicked.
/// Shows the camera capture UI in photo mode.
/// When the user takes a photo, shows the image in output section.
/// </summary>
void CapturePhoto::CapturePhoto_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    try
    {
        CameraCaptureUI^ dialog = ref new CameraCaptureUI();

        concurrency::task<StorageFile^> getPhotoFromCamera(dialog->CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode::Photo));

        auto getStreamTask = getPhotoFromCamera.then([](Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^storageFile)
        {
            return storageFile->OpenReadAsync();
        });

        getStreamTask.then([this](Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType ^storageFile)
        {

            MyBitmap = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            MyBitmap->SetSource(storageFile);
            byte* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(MyBitmap->PixelBuffer);
            int height = MyBitmap->PixelHeight;
            int width = MyBitmap->PixelWidth;

            // create a matrix the size and type of the image
            cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC4);
            memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, 4 * height*width);

            // convert to grayscale
            cv::Mat intermediateMat;
            cv::cvtColor(mat, intermediateMat, CV_RGB2GRAY);

            // convert to BGRA
            cv::cvtColor(intermediateMat, mat, CV_GRAY2BGRA);

            cv::CascadeClassifier faceHaar;
            std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

            try
            {
                faceHaar.detectMultiScale(mat, faces); // , 1.1, 3, 0, cv::Size(30, 30), cv::Size(1000, 1000));
            }
            catch (Platform::Exception^ e)
            {
                std::string mystr = ":(";
            }
            std::string mystr = "foobar";
        });
    }
    catch (Platform::Exception^ ex)
    {
        rootPage->NotifyUser(ex->Message, NotifyType::ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Update:

```
void CapturePhoto::CapturePhoto_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    try
    {
        CameraCaptureUI^ dialog = ref new CameraCaptureUI();

        concurrency::task<StorageFile^> getPhotoFromCamera(dialog->CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode::Photo));

        auto getStreamTask = getPhotoFromCamera.then([](Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^storageFile)
        {
            return storageFile->OpenReadAsync();
        });

        getStreamTask.then([this](Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType ^storageFile)
        {

            MyBitmap = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            MyBitmap->SetSource(storageFile);
            byte* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(MyBitmap->PixelBuffer);
            int height = MyBitmap->PixelHeight;
            int width = MyBitmap->PixelWidth;

            // create a matrix the size and type of the image
            cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC4);
            memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, 4 * height*width);

            // convert to grayscale
            cv::Mat intermediateMat;
            cv::cvtColor(mat, intermediateMat, CV_RGB2GRAY);
            //cv::cvtColor(intermediateMat, mat, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
            //cv::cvtColor(mat, intermediateMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            //cv::equalizeHist(intermediateMat, mat);

            cv::CascadeClassifier faceHaar;
            faceHaar.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

            faceHaar.detectMultiScale(intermediateMat, faces); // , 1.1, 3, 0, cv::Size(30, 30), cv::Size(5000, 5000));

            std::string mystr = "foobar";
        });
    }
    catch (Platform::Exception^ ex)
    {
        rootPage->NotifyUser(ex->Message, NotifyType::ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what opencv says when throwing an exception? (you can find such information on console output).

Comment: What are all those `^` in the code?

Comment: faceHaar.detectMultiScale(mat, faces); // you will have to load a cascade file before being able to do so.

Comment: I am unable to work on this while at the office, but I didn't notice I wasn't loading a cascade. I lost that line somewhere in my many refactorings. And, the hat symbol is a winrt specific reference.

Comment: Loading a cascade helped, but no faces are detected. I've tried conversion between cvtColors and equalizeHist as I've seen in examples  with no luck.

Comment: I was able to detect faces by increasing the photo quality, though it is not as reliable as I hoped. I'll have to experiment with the parameter values and see if there is a sweet spot.